# How can I refer to the first file in an .xcfilelist within an Xcode build script?

Tags: xcode, xcode13

How can I refer to the first file in an .xcfilelist within an Xcode build script?

If I list the files separately (instead of using an .xcfilelist) then I can use SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0 of course. However if I use a .xcfilelist instead, then how can I reference that first output file?

The only reason we want to use the .xcfilelist in the first place is so Xcode doesn't re-run the script and rebuild the module every single time we run a compile. However that's exactly what it's doing... it seems to be ignoring what's specified in the output file list's .xcfilelist and always regenerating those files and then recompiling them even when nothing has changed.

Seems like an Xcode bug but figured maybe we could compare the modification times at the beginning of the script by referencing the first file in the file list, but I cannot seem to find a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over all lines in all `xcfilelist`s then this simplistic script can do it:

```bash
for index in $(seq $SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_LIST_COUNT); do
    # 1 => `SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_LIST_0`
    filelist=SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_LIST_$((index-1))
    # `SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_LIST_0` => value in $SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_LIST_0
    filelist_path=${!filelist}

    while read -r file_path; do
        echo "${file_path}"
    done <$filelist_path
done
```

It will dynamically construct the `SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_LIST_0`, `SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_LIST_1`, etc. values and access them from the environment vars passed to the script by Xcode.